# Char $p$ fields, extension/subextension

Tags: galois-theory, galois-extensions

Let $K = \mathbb{F}_{p}$ (A prime field with char $= p$)

Let $C|K$ an algebraic closure of $K$

Then if $F$ is a field such that $K\subset F \subset C$, and $F \not= C \implies |F|<\infty$

Can someone help me?

Comment: It’s not true. Consider the union (direct limit) of the extensions of $K$ of degree $2^n$.

Comment: Thank you! I am disconcerted :(

Comment: Why this union is not algebraically closed?

Comment: Because it does not contain the extension of degree three, nor indeed any extension that is not of degree a power of $2$. You are clearly under the impression that the Galois group is something like $\Bbb Z_p$, with a totally ordered lattice of subgroups. The truth is much more interesting, since the Galois group is (isomorphic to) $\widehat{\Bbb Z}$.